# Unable to locate package libxp6 on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I want to launch matlab, this error appears:

`/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: error while loading shared libraries: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I already tried to install libxp6 by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxp6
```

and I already searched for this

```
apt-cache search libxp
```

but there is no package with this name. 
My operating system is Ubuntu 16.10.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

### **UPDATE:**

It seems they removed the libxp6 package from the stable list. However, you are still able to obtain the oldstable on this page:

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libxp6

The installation of this package is still the same as described below!

---

I also just had this problem.

Try this, this worked for me:

---

### Long answer:

Download **libxp6** on this page manually: https://packages.debian.org/stable/libs/libxp6

(At the bottom of the page you will see "**Download libxp6**")

Make sure to checkout what architecture you have on your Linux system by using this command:

```
uname -a
```

After you find it out, click the link with your architecture on the page (for example: **architecture: amd64**, and below you will see some location, where you can download from it, for example:

**North America:**

> ftp.us.debian.org/debian

This is just a link to this real download link:

```
ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
```

On your linux command line you just can run this:

```
wget ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
```

After the download is finished, you can install it with this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
```

**libxp6** has been successfully installed!

---

### Short answer:

Run this command on your linux command line:

> Where yy is, replace your location. Where xx is, replace your
>   architecture.

```
wget ftp.yy.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_xx.deb
```

**Example:**

```
wget ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
```

After the download, run this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i libxp6_1.0.2-2_xx.deb
```

**Example:**

```
sudo dpkg -i libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
```

**libxp6** has been successfully installed!

---

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Seems like they removed libxp6 from the stable list. Try one of these here: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libxp6 
Check which architecture you have (uname -a) and download the corresponding file. The rest should work as I explained above.

Comment: Got the oldstable one and it works, perhaps you could add it to your answer

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! i just updated my answer so that everyone can see it.